# C# WPF MVVM | Adding new object not shown in list

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, combobox

I'd like to find a way to add a Car to a Branch like to you see on the image below.

[Add Car to Branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5VvP.png)

When I press the button "Bewaar" (aka Save) it will store it in the database, but it won't show in the application because it's not linked to any Branch. I can't seem to find the solution for this, tried changing the Car class and tried to manipulate some code in the ViewModels.

This image show's the query (select * from Filiaal)
[Show Car in database Branches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05w6U.png)

**Translations from images**

- Filialen = Branches
- Filiaal = Branch
- Naam Bestuurder = Name Driver
- Merk Wagen = Brand Car
- Type Wagen = Car Type
- Bewaar = Save
- Annuleer = Cancel

**Code Below**

ComboBox Code from AddWagenView.xaml

```
<ComboBox
                Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Filialen}"
                >
            </ComboBox>
```

Car Class

```
namespace EB.BedrijfswagenBeheer.Data
{
    [Table("tblWagens")]
    public class Wagen
    {
        //Fields
        private string _type;
        private string _merk;
        private string _bestuurder;

        //Constructors

        internal Wagen() : this(null, null)
        {

        }
        internal Wagen(int id, string type, string merk)
        {
            Id = id;
            Type = type;
            Merk = merk;
        }

        internal Wagen(int id, string type, string merk, string bestuurder)
        {
            Id = id;
            Type = type;
            Merk = merk;
            Bestuurder = bestuurder;
        }

        public Wagen(String type, String merk) : this(0, type, merk)
        {

        }

        public Wagen(String type, String merk, String bestuurder) : this(0, type, merk, bestuurder)
        { }



        //Properties
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        // Elke wagen heeft een type. (Voorbeelden: PickUp, SUV, Coupé, Camionette, ...)
        public String Type 
        {
            get { return _type; }
            set { _type = value; }
        }

        // Elke wagen heeft een merk. (Voorbeelden: Citroën, BMW, Volkswagen, Skoda, Mercedes, Audi, ...)
        public String Merk
        {
            get { return _merk; }
            set { _merk = value; }
        }

        // Een wagen behoort tot een bestuurder.
        public String Bestuurder
        {
            get { return _bestuurder; }
            set { _bestuurder = value; }
        }

        //Methods
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Merk} ({Type}) - {Bestuurder}";
        }
    }
}
```

Filiaal Class

```
namespace EB.BedrijfswagenBeheer.Data
{
    [Table("tblFilialen")]
    public class Filiaal
    {
        //Constructors
        internal Filiaal() : this(null)
        {}
        internal Filiaal(int id, string naam)
        {
            Id = id;
            Naam = naam;
            Wagens = new List<Wagen>();
        }
        public Filiaal(String naam) : this(0, naam)
        {}

        //Properties
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String Naam { get; set; }

        //Lijst van wagens binnenin een filiaal
        public List<Wagen> Wagens { get; set; }

        //Methodes
        //Tonen naam van filialen en de aantaal wagens binnenin het filiaal
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Naam} (#{Wagens.Count} wagens)";
        }
    }
}
```

WagenAddViewModel

```
namespace EB.BedrijfswagenBeheer.App.ViewModels
{
    class WagenAddViewModel :  BaseViewModel
    {
        private BedrijfswagenBeheerRepository _repository;
        private Wagen _addWagen = new Wagen("","");
        private ObservableCollection<Filiaal> _filialen;

        public WagenAddViewModel(BedrijfswagenBeheerRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
            _filialen = _repository.GetFilialen();

            SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveChanges);
            CancelCommand = new RelayCommand(CancelChanges);

            Titel = "Add Wagen";
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Filiaal> Filialen
        {
            get { return _filialen; }
            set
            {
                if (_filialen != value)
                {
                    _filialen = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }


        public Wagen AddWagen
        {
            get { return _addWagen; }
            set
            {
                if (_addWagen != value)
                {
                    _addWagen = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }


        public event Action<Boolean> ReturnToViewRequested;


        #region SaveCommand
        public RelayCommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }

        public void SaveChanges()
        {
            _repository.AddWagen(AddWagen);
            AddWagen = new Wagen("", "");
            ReturnToViewRequested?.Invoke(true);
        }
        #endregion SaveCommand

        #region CancelCommand
        public RelayCommand CancelCommand { get; set; }

        public void CancelChanges()
        {
            AddWagen = new Wagen("","");
            ReturnToViewRequested?.Invoke(false);
        }
        #endregion CancelCommand
    }
}
```

The view with all the cars shown (FiliaalDetailViewViewModel)
[Image with the right side shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iC7Di.png)

```
namespace EB.BedrijfswagenBeheer.App.ViewModels
{
    public class FiliaalDetailViewViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        //Fields
        private BedrijfswagenBeheerRepository _repository;
        private Wagen _wagen;
        private Filiaal _filiaal;
        private ObservableCollection<Filiaal> _filialen;
        private ObservableCollection<Wagen> _wagens;
        private Wagen _selectedWagen;

        //Constructors
        public FiliaalDetailViewViewModel(BedrijfswagenBeheerRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;

            Titel = "Wagens";

            DeleteCommand = new RelayCommand(DeleteWagen, CanDeleteWagen);
            EditCommand = new RelayCommand<Wagen>(EditWagen, CanEditWagen);
            AddCommand = new RelayCommand(AddWagen);
        }

        //Add Wagen
        public ObservableCollection<Wagen> Wagens
        {
            get { return _wagens; }
            set
            {
                if (_wagens != value)
                {
                    _wagens = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Filiaal> Filialen
        {
            get { return _filialen; }
            set
            {
                if (_filialen != value)
                {
                    _filialen = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        //Properties

        public Wagen Wagen
        {
            get { return _wagen; }
            set
            {
                if (_wagen != value)
                {
                    _wagen = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                    Titel = $"Wagen: {Wagen}";
                }
            }
        }
        public Filiaal Filiaal
        {
            get { return _filiaal; }
            set
            {
                if (_filiaal != value)
                {
                    _filiaal = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                    Titel = $"Filiaal: {Filiaal}";
                }
            }
        }
        public Wagen SelectedWagen
        {
            get { return _selectedWagen; }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedWagen != value)
                {
                    _selectedWagen = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }


        //Methods

        #region AddWagen
        public RelayCommand AddCommand { get; private set; }

        public event Action AddWagenRequested;

        public void AddWagen()
        {
            AddWagenRequested?.Invoke();
        }


        #endregion AddWagen

        public void RefreshFilialen()
        {
            Filialen = _repository.GetFilialen();
        }

        #region DeleteWagen
        public RelayCommand DeleteCommand { get; private set; }

        public void DeleteWagen()
        {
            MessageBoxResult result =  MessageBox.Show($"Zeker dat je '{SelectedWagen.ToString()}' wilt verwijderen?", $"Verwijder Wagen", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
            if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                _repository.DeleteWagen(SelectedWagen);
                RefreshFilialen();
                RefreshWagens();
            }
            
        }

        private Boolean CanDeleteWagen()
        {
            return SelectedWagen != null;
        }
        public void RefreshWagens()
        {
            Wagens = _repository.GetWagens();
        }
        
        #endregion DeleteWagen

        #region EditWagen
        public RelayCommand<Wagen> EditCommand { get; private set; }
        public event Action<Wagen> EditWagenRequested;
        public void EditWagen(Wagen wagen)
        {
            EditWagenRequested?.Invoke(wagen);
        }

        public Boolean CanEditWagen(Wagen wagen)
        {
            return wagen != null;
        }

        #endregion EditWagen

    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you add something to `Filialen`? I suspect you don't and then you are missing refreshing: assign `Filialen = _repository.GetFilialen()` each time you modifiy data.

Comment: @Sinatr I added a class in my post, I think you are referring to that one or not? In that class I have the DeleteCommand where I call the refresh. But that doesn't assign any Filiaal to the Car

Comment: When you do  _repository.AddWagen(AddWagen); that is a reference to a car object. You then do AddWagen = new Wagen("", "");  You're changing the same object. You should clone the wagen or something and pass that to the repository. Make sure that different object is used to the thing you're re-setting. And call the two things different names.